# Add pdf file in Rmarkdown file

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

Is it possible to display a pdf file in an Rmarkdown file? Say, for example, a previously saved image `myimage.pdf`

What I am aiming is a form of

```
\includegraphics[width=0.5]{myimage.pdf}
```

Comment: Yes, pdf_output supports raw latex, so you can do as you suggested. You'll need to put units on the width, though.

Comment: I was able to do as you said and include it in the pdf output, thanks. Is there a way to include it in the HTML output?

Comment: Not unless you convert it to png or jpeg first.

Answer (score 7):

**An update from the very end of 2017**

It is possible to import a PDF image using `knitr::include_graphics()`, e.g.

````
```{r label, out.width = "85%", fig.cap = "caption"}
include_graphics("path-to-your-image.pdf") 
```
````

Comment: **knitr::include_graphics("path-to-your-image.pdf")** worked for me, but **include_graphics("path-to-your-image.pdf")** did not. Is it possible that you missed to add  **knitr::** in your example?

Comment: Sure. I assume you load knit at the very beginning

Comment: Nice that this sorta works now, but the size control does nothing for me in knitr 1.20

Answer (score 2):

You can insert this directly into your R Markdown. The alternate name will only be displayed if the image does not load.

```
![Alternate Name](file.pdf){width=500px}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record and as suggested in the comments, this works perfectly fine as long as you're knitting to pdf (this is a LaTex command that won't work if you try to knit to HTML or docx though):

```
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{myimage.pdf}
```

You can change the width with something like

```
\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{myimage.pdf}
```